# Solving the Diophantine equation $x^2 +2ax - y^2 = b$ in relation to Integer Factoring

Tags: diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms, prime-factorization

Is there a method we could use for solving the Diophantine equation $x^2 +2ax - y^2 = b$?

**Background:**

Consider a very large integer $z$ that we want to factor (not necessarily prime factorization, but finding $pq = z$).

[image: Tiling example]

Say we have $z$ unit square tiles. We start laying them out as squares.
The squares up to the green ones in the layout is the largest square we are able to form with $z$ tiles and the square tiles that are enclosed in thick black border are the residual tiles that are not part of a complete square.

i.e,.  $z = s^2 + c, s=\lfloor \sqrt z \rfloor, c = z \mod s$.

Now we start removing the green squares (the green squares after removal are shown in yellow in the figure above) and place them around the square of dimension $s^2$. After the yellow squares are placed, we are showing them in blue in the figure above.

So, we have the equation

$x^2 + 2sx - c = y^2$

Rearranging,

$x^2 +2sx - y^2 = c$

This is a Diophantine equation of the form $x^2 + 2ax - y^2 = b$ given in the question where the coefficients on the LHS and the constant on the RHS have been replaced with $s, c$ respectively.

**Approach so far:**

In general, if we are free to choose $s$ such that $z = s^2 + c, c \ge 0$, we could choose $s$ from the range $[1, \lfloor \sqrt z \rfloor]$.

Noticing that the LHS is a quadratic form, we can choose $y$ as a parameter where $-y^2 = uv$ for integers $u, v$ and $u + v = 2s$. If we are able to find such a $y, u, v$, we can represent the LHS as the product of two linear factors in $x$. We would have reduced the factoring of a large $z$ into a smaller problem of factoring hopefully a small $c$.

We could then recursively perform factorization of $c$ using the same procedure until we get to a $c \lt \beta$, a smooth bound where we could just do trial division.

**Questions:**

- Is there an intelligent search procedure for $s$ and $c$ that helps us in factoring $z$ in polynomial time?

Comment: your title has $x^2 + 2ay- y^2$ and the first sentence has $x^2 + 2ax- y^2.$ You were asking recently about binary quadratic forms, that would be $$ x^2 + 2axy - y^2 $$ In this case,you want the later Brillhart article on factoring.

Comment: the 2009 article was on positive forms http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Brillhart_Euler_factoring_2009.pdf

Comment: Sorry, title had the error. I have fixed it.

Comment: well, here is Brillhart 2016 http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Brillhart_Euler_factoring_2016.pdf    Your version is just $(x+a)^2 - y^2 = b + a^2$

Comment: @WillJagy: That's right. I was trying to avoid factoring $a^2+b$ or representing it as difference of two squares. Looks like there is no way around that.

Comment: vvgiri  There is a simple idea that you should investigate. Whatever you are trying to do with a large number you may not be able to factor: assume you succeed in the task you have described. Does your solution lead quickly to a factoring of the original(perhaps just a pair of factors)? You already knew about a difference of squares. Another example is the difference (or sum) of cubes. We often get questions trying to avoid factoring, about some method that produces a factoring, therefore is equivalent, in any case no faster.

Comment: meanwhile, there are sometimes posts about methods in ancient India, the one I recall (because of Pell) are https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chakravala_method  and yuo can search for text strings within this site. I will see about this memory

Comment: not bad, https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=chakravala  you may then read those posts, look at profile pages for the people asking and answering, see what relate questions they may have asked/answered